# Create a WSO2 Api Manager policy as a Carbon Application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to create and deploy API Policy as a carbon application, without having to use Api Manager UI or CLI tools to upload?

A policy is, after all, just a sequence and some metadata. Would it be possible to package it in a car file and deploy in API Manager?

Answer (score 0):

With the newer APIM versions you will not be able to, as this will break the UI functionality where you engage the policies to APIs.